# No permission to write to disk on Windows Server 2008 from .NET application with log4net

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008, log4net, file-permissions

I wrote a simple application which pings my webservice to see if it's up, and logs the events to a file, using log4net for it.

It works fine on my development machine, but when I put the assembly on other Windows Server 2008 machine (which is also different from the server which runs the service I ping), the program  does not create the log file.

I run it from an account in Administrators group, tried to put it in different directories on the server, run it "As administrator", gave all permissions to the folder to all the users groups I have on the server, but still got no log file.

Get no error messages and no event messages in the events log.

these are my log4net conf. settings:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="MyServiceLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the server to see if the application is giving any errors?

Comment: yes. I checked in the application and security logs, there were no errors, and actually no entries about the activity of the application. I know that the process is running for sure though, I see it's window.

Comment: If the application cannot write to the server then it should be throwing exceptions, which should be visible in your application's window.

Comment: maybe log4net eats up exceptions... is there a way to tell him to bubble the exceptions out? maybe i'll try file.write() by myself see if something happens...

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Check out [this page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) and search for **"How do I enable log4net internal debugging?"**

Comment: Have you tried catching exceptions and throwing them to the console? You can then run your app and pipe the output to a text file, and see what it throws.

Comment: I just gave up and wrote to file with  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(LOG_PATH, text) - works well in every place. Must be some problem with Log4net. It also didn't work on my machine from directory other then the directory the compiler put it into.

Comment: Seems like an IT problem - the user running the process has no right to write to that dir or the user you are using is not defined as local machine admin.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a folder name in the:

```
<file value="MyServiceLog.txt" />
```

Change it to:

```
<file value="c:\dirIown\MyServiceLog.txt" />
```

than make sure you give access to the user on `c:\dirIown`

Comment: tried to put it in different dirs. eventually i did it on my own with file.write()..